# UIViewControllerのサブクラスにdidReceiveMemoryWarningメソッドを必ず書く必要がありますか。

Tags: ios

iOSアプリ開発において、UIViewControllerのサブクラスを自前で作ることがよくあります。
その際に、参考にする記事などで、以下のように`didReceiveMemoryWarning`メソッドがオーバーライドされていることがよくあります。

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

これは、ただスーパークラスの`didReceiveMemoryWarning`を呼んでいるだけですが、サブクラス独自の処理を書かない場合でもこのメソッドはオーバーライドするべきなのでしょうか。
スーパークラスのメソッドを呼ぶだけなら`didReceiveMemoryWarning`自体書かなくても良いのではないかと思い質問させて頂きました。
初歩的な質問で恐縮ですが何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おっしゃる通りです。ただスーパークラスのメソッドを呼んでるだけなら、書かなくても同じ意味ですので書く必要はありません。